# Is it possible to query the diff between two Apache Iceberg snapshots?

Tags: apache-iceberg

I have two snapshots in my Iceberg history table, and I want to be able to see the difference between them, or at least with columns/ rows that have been affected on the last snapshot. Is there an easy way of getting this information?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the java api to get the incremental change log between two snapshot id in a table.

```
table
    .newIncrementalChangelogScan()
    .fromSnapshotExclusive(startSnapshotId)
    .toSnapshot(toSnapshot)
    .caseSensitive(caseSensitive)
    .filter(filterExpression())
    .project(expectedSchema)
    .planTasks();
```

It will get the full change log.

If you just want to query incremental data, an easier way is to use spark or flink:

```
spark.read()
  .format("iceberg")
  .option("start-snapshot-id", "10963874102873")
  .option("end-snapshot-id", "63874143573109")
  .load("path/to/table")
```

Currently gets only the data from append operation. Cannot support replace, overwrite, delete operations.

Enjoy yourself.